# Text shifting on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` with an `<img>` element inside, and text in the center. When the `<div>` is hovered on, the opacity of the image changes. If the image is hovered over, the text goes to the left a pixel, then back again.

```css
.mainimage {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}

.mainimageimg {
  opacity: 0.8;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.mainimageimg:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.mainimageheading {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 2.35em;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainimage">
  <img class="mainimageimg" src="https://wallpaper-house.com/data/out/8/wallpaper2you_232687.jpg" draggable="false">
  <h1 class="mainimageheading">Text here</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I have taken the code that you had in your initial revision and put it into a runnable snippet verbatim.  However, I am not seeing the issue that you have described.  Can you please edit your question and update the snippet to reproduce the issue or explain in greater detail the issue that you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.mainimage {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
}
.mainimageimg {
    opacity:0.8;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.mainimage:hover .mainimageimg {
    opacity: 1;
}
.mainimage:hover .mainimageheading{
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.mainimageheading {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    user-select: none;
    font-size: 2.35em;
    transition: 1s all ease;
}
```